# how many draws does Nate need until the expected number of diamonds he picks is 1

Tags: expected-value

> A chest contains 4 rubies, 8 emeralds, 3 diamonds, and 3 sapphires.
> Nate will draw jewels one at a time. After each draw, he puts the
> jewels back into the chest. Nate will go free if he picks some
> diamonds. How many draws does Nate need until the expected number of
> diamonds he picks is 1?

The expected value is the number of diamonds. I assume there are $n$ draws. Since he puts the jewels back, I think $P(diamond)=\frac{3}{18}=\frac{1}{6}$. Therefore, $P(not diamond)=\frac{5}{6}$.

I assume there are $n$ draws. There are n possible outcomes.
I use $A$ to represent diamonds and $B$ to represent rubies & emeralds & sapphires.

1. $1$ draw: $P(A)=\frac{1}{6}$
2. $2$ draws: $P(BA)=\frac{5}{6}*\frac{1}{6}$
3. $3$ draws: $P(BBA)=\frac{5}{6}^2*\frac{1}{6}$
   ...
4. $n$ draws: $P(BB...A)=\frac{5}{6}^{n-1}*\frac{1}{6}$.

$E[X]=\frac{1}{6}+2*\frac{5}{6}*\frac{1}{6}+3*\frac{5}{6}^2*\frac{1}{6}*\frac{1}{6}+...+n*\frac{5}{6}^{n-1}*\frac{1}{6}$.

Can anyone tell me if I'm correct?

Comment: Hint: when he makes a draw, with the probability of 1/6 it is a diamonds or with the probability of 5/6 the process starts again.

Comment: @Gray_Rhino So does it mean in every draw of the $n$ draws, there is a 5/6 chance of not being diamond and 1/6 of being diamond?

Comment: Yes, that is because each time is identical and independent of previous time.

Comment: Regarding your second question: when there's no diamonds P(diamond) = 0 so P(no diamond) = 1- P(diamond) = 1

Comment: Your expression for $E[X]$ is correct (or it would be correct if it didn't stop after $n$ terms). Can you evaluate it? If you do, you will find that it gives the same answer as @Gray_Rhino's simpler method.

Comment: @TonyK Hi, I got 6 eventually.

Comment: Correct!${}{}{}$